# Webstorm 11, log xhrs requests

Tags: ajax, webstorm

I'm debugging angular app with webstorm 11. I've installed jetbrains extension for chrome and set up js debug configuration. I'm seeing console, current dom elements and scripts but i don't see ajax requests. Does WS debugger provide this feature? I don't want to switch to chrome dev console in order to see ajax request/responses.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't:( Please vote for [WEB-7394](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7394) to be notified on any progress with this feature